# Bootstrap navbar background changing when I want it to not change

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

https://github.com/cooperlappenbusch/coopernaumwebsite

I am having some issues with the navbar in Bootstrap, I mainly do programming so I am new to bootstrap, I had a hard time finding an answer to my problem as most of the results I've looked at are the opposite of what I want.

I want the background of my navbar list to **NOT** change when I hover over it, I've tried to set the background color when hovering over the list item and I've tried a bunch of other stuff but nothing seems to work.

Please help me out if you can.

TL;DR: When hovering over my list item in my navbar, I want to have the background color not change.

(if you want, don't even look at the code and just give me some general tips on this type of issue )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this to force the colors.

```
.navbar a:focus, .navbar a:hover, .navbar a {
   background:blue !important;
   color:black !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me out alot and now I understand now how to edit the main bootstrap to customize my website, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this with CSS but I will give jQuery solution

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var navs = $('.nav')// all navs  or links 
var orgStyle = navs.first().CSS('background-color') 
navs.mouseover(function(){
$(this).CSS('background-color', orgStyle); // reset to the 
org style 
});
});
```

done.
This is an Example by my mobile so sorry for my bad formater

Answer (score 0):

Navbar menu item gets that grey background because, a CSS rule for `:focus` on the anchor element is pre-defined in bootstrap.css

You can overwrite the rule using below CSS.

Try This CSS.

```
   .navbar .nav li a:hover,
   .navbar .nav li a:focus{
       background-color:transparent;
   }
```